# Fetch Youtube Private videos using gdata API

Tags: php, youtube, gdata-api, gdata

I want a simple way so retrieve all user's uploads on Youtube including private videos. I'm using PHP and gdata API, and I do not want to use Zend Gdata.

Any ideas or approaches to do that ?

Comment: Using Zend Gdata is prolly the simplest way there is. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I'm not able to setup it, as I need a generic solution that can be used by other frameworks or CMSs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zend Gdata as a 'generic solution'. For example in this code snippet, I am getting the number of views of this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ5tt6_guR4&feature=feedrec_grec_index). No need for use with the Zend framework. As you can see I am using the PHP CLI for this one:

```
php > require_once 'Zend/Uri/Http.php';
php > require_once 'Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php';
php > $x = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
php > $x->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
php > $v = $x->getVideoEntry("zZ5tt6_guR4")->getVideoViewCount();
php > echo $v;
1874357
```

For your purposes, you can see more details on how to use it over [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html).

The key is to include the necessary php files. In my example btw, my Zend files are on the include path.

Comment: This is correct - there's no need to use any other Zend Framework components. You can get the Zend_Gdata files as a standalone package [here](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata). I am using this setup for one of my projects and it works fine.

Comment: Will this include the private videos ( schedules to be published in future ) ?

Comment: I think for private videos you need to get a an auth sub token first before you can get information such as number of views.